# How to add newly added data from firebase to the top of the recyclerview and not at the bottom? Please see details

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an app in which I'm retrieving some data from `Firebase` database.

The problem is that everytime I save something, it gets retrieved and gets added to the bottom of the `RecyclerView`.

What I want is I want the newly added data to get added to the top of the recyclerview and not at the bottom.

I have no idea how to do what I want to do.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well first of all the question is about `recyclerview` and you posted code of your data retrieval. and if your want to add a new item to recycler view use

```
mArrayList.add(position, item);
notifyItemInserted(position);
```

for data to be inserted in first row use

```
mArrayList.add(0, item);
notifyItemInserted(0);
```

and then you can use `mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);` to scroll to the top.

Comment: awesome. this did the job! can you please have a look at this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023511/how-to-place-ads-randomly-in-between-of-recyclerview-please-see-details Please?...

Answer (score 3):

try something like

```
Query lastToFirstQuery = databaseReference.orderBy("something_in_your_database").limitToLast(datasnapshot.numChildren());

lastToFirstQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Map<String, String> newRequest = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            imageUID = newRequest.get("imageUIDh");
            hDescription = newRequest.get("hDescription");
            currentLat = newRequest.get("currentLat");
            currentLng = newRequest.get("currentLng");
            postedBy = newRequest.get("postedBy");
            postedAtTime = newRequest.get("postedAtTime");
            postedOnDate = newRequest.get("postedOnDate");
            utcFormatDateTime = newRequest.get("utcFormatDateTime");

        } 

        @Override 
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        } 

        @Override 
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        } 

        @Override 
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        } 

        @Override 
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(coordinatorLayout, databaseError.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            snackbar.setDuration(Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
            snackbar.show();
            progressBarLoading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } 
    });
```

Comment: M. Waqas answer solved the issue. Thanks for your answer too. 
Can you please have a look at this too: stackoverflow.com/questions/38023511/… Please?..